# Nontrivial Stabilizers of Symmetric Matrices Under Permutation Actions

Tags: matrices, group-theory, reference-request, permutations, representation-theory

**Question**: Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix, and consider the action of the permutation group $S_n$ on the space of such symmetric matrices by conjugation: $S\cdot A = S^TAS$ where $S$ is an $n\times n$ permutation matrix.

Define the stabilizer of $A$ with respect to $S_n$ as
$$
\text{Stab}_{S_n}(A) = \{S\in S_n\mid S^TAS=A\}.
$$
I'm interested in characterizing the properties or conditions on $A$ that ensure $\text{Stab}_{S_n}(A)$ is nontrivial, i.e., contains more elements than just the identity permutation.

**Thoughts**: Given that permutation matrices are a subset of orthogonal matrices, we have $\text{Stab}_{S_n}(A) \subseteq \text{Stab}_{O(n)}(A)$. Thus, the cardinality of $\text{Stab}_{S_n}(A)$ cannot exceed that of $\text{Stab}_{O(n)}(A)$. The stabilizer $\text{Stab}_{O(n)}(A)$ is nontrivial if $A$ possesses repeated nonzero eigenvalues or zero eigenvalues, e.g., $A = I_n$. However, this yields a necessary condition for a nontrivial $\text{Stab}_{S_n}(A)$, but not a sufficient one.

Additionally, I'm considering the requirement that $A$ should have at least two identical diagonal entries, with their respective columns being permutations of one another. However, a counter-example can be easily found, e.g.,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 1 & 4 & 3\\
3 & 4 & 7 & 8\\
4 & 3 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where permuting the first two columns will not produce the same $A$ and $\text{Stab}_{S_n}(A)$ is trivial. I wonder what additional considerations can ensure nontrivial $\text{Stab}_{S_n}(A)$.

Any insights or references related to this topic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ can be interpreted as the [weighted adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of a weighted undirected graph, namely a graph in which each edge is labeled by a real number. (If the numbers are non-negative these can be interpreted as lengths.) Then you are asking about the automorphism group of this graph (in the weighted sense, so preserving the edge weights).

As far as sufficient conditions I don't know that there's anything more to say than that. A graph has a nontrivial automorphism if it has a nontrivial automorphism, that condition doesn't really simplify at all. Note that the actual real numbers involved are irrelevant and as far as the automorphism group goes they might as well be "colors," so  you can think of this as really being about graphs where the edges have some colors and automorphisms have to be color-preserving. In other words this is a purely combinatorial question.

Necessary conditions are more interesting. Generalizing your observation about eigenspaces, if a finite group $G$ acts faithfully on a weighted graph then it also acts on the eigenspaces of its adjacency matrix, so those eigenspaces must have dimensions which are sums of dimensions of the irreducible representations of $G$. I give a few examples in [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/the-schrodinger-equation-on-a-finite-graph/) where I was trying to use this observation as a toy model of the use of irreducible representations in quantum mechanics.

Combining this observation with the observation about "colors" we actually do not have to restrict ourself to the eigenspaces of the matrix $A$ itself; we are free to replace the distinct entries of $A$ with distinct entries of any field, so e.g. we could take them to be algebraically independent indeterminates. That should generally have the effect of reducing the size of the eigenspaces.